# areas of a circle for multiple radii- list object is not callable

Tags: list, syntax-error, area

I am getting a 'list object is not callable' error- any help?

import math

```
def area(r):
    return math.pi * (r**2)          

radii = [2,5,7.1,0.3,10]

areas = []
for r in radii:
    a = area(r)
    areas.append(a)

print(areas())
```

Comment: I believe you mean `print(areas())` to be `print(areas)`. The `()` calls whatever object comes before it.

Comment: Ahh awesome, I didn't know that about (), thanks for the response!